# associative array into columns of database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I need help on storing associative array into database columns in codeigniter.

I have a input field named "vehicle[]", actually this one this consist of 8 fields like Make, Model, color etc.

also the user can add one more more vehicles using "Add another" option which the input fields same as vehicle[]

here's my code for Model of codeigniter

```
public function vehicle($new){

    $new = $this->input->post('vehicle');

    $data = array(
        'vehicle_number' => json_encode($new),
        'make'       => json_encode($new),
        'color'       => json_encode($new),
         'color'       => json_encode(model),
    );
    $this->db->insert('vehicles_tbl', $data);
```

this way the all he data stored in a one column of the database, how can i store each value in related column of the database.

```
My controller

$this->vehicle_model->vehicle($new);
```

[image: my application]

Comment: Doesn't the Codeigniter docs go through how to use databases? Btw. You're code doesn't make sense. You have two array keys called `'color'` in the same array. The second one will overwrite the first one and why do you "json_encode()` the data before you save it in the database?

Comment: After looking a bit more on CI's way of handling DB-queries, it doesn't seem like they are using prepared statements but have their own implementation for "query bindings", which is reason enough to drop that framework... or include another, secure, DB-library.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson i have 8 input fields(make, color, chassis, model, engine,number,tyre, battery) all are named as vehicle[], by default a user can add 1 vehicle if they have more vehicles, can user Add feature to add the details of another vehicle which also have the same fields. all i want i save the data of this array in respect columns

Comment: Like I said, the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) explains how to insert data. If vehicle is an array, just fetch the data as an array: `$data = array('model' => $new['model], ...and so on);`

Comment: can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You should code like this
 //view

```
< input type="text" name="vehicle_number[]">
< input type="text" name="make[]">
< input type="text" name="color[]">
< input type="text" name="model[]">
```

// Model

public function vehicle(){

```
$new = $this->input->post('vehicle_number');



for ($i=0; $i <count($new) ; $i++) { 

    $data[] = array(
        'vehicle_number' => $_POST['vehicle_number'][$i],
        'make'       => $_POST['make'][$i],
        'color'       => $_POST['color'][$i],
        'model'       =>$_POST['model'][$i],
        );

}
```

return $this->db->insert_batch('vehicles_tbl', $data);

Comment: thanks, but i have someting like this

< input type="text" name="vehicler[]">
< input type="text" name="vehicler[]">
< input type="text" name="vehicler[]">
< input type="text" name="vehicler[]">

Comment: have a look at my image i have a feature to add another vehicle if they want.

goes like this 

default v1 - number, model, color, etc then add new ..... which will give same input boxes to add second vechicle

Comment: also why is only $new = $this->input->post('vehicle_number');
there does it have to be other post values as well?